# VBA macro in excel that will copy and paste a range of cells into another sheet weekly

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA but have a need use it in a report I run weekly.  There are six columns that I need to copy and paste into another sheet each week - this would be cumulative so it would paste the new data after the old data each week, not replace it.  The range for this case is A6:A24 through F6:F24. One additionally caveat is that I would like to add one column called date that posts that days date - is that doable? I have attached a snippet - my idea is to create the column headers in the new tab (manager, employee, etc.) and fill data down each week so I can create a chart with historical data.  [image]

Adding what I have come up with:

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
'Method 1
Sheets("Summary Build").Range("A6:F24").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
End Sub
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: when I say new to VBA I mean really new lol just starting to learn- I have copied a few of our existing VBA statments and made adjustments successfully but having trouble with pasting at the end specifically - i.e. going to the end of the results and pasting there each week.

Comment: I have added what I came up with in the above - it works good for posting into those cells but I need it to move down to the first empty row in 'A' each week and paste again - adding the date would be great too.

Comment: Could you add an example of the end result you are trying to reach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there. Your code will copy to A2. To find the next blank cell you need to start at the bottom of the spreadsheet, go up to the first filled  cell and then down one. Bottom of the spreadsheet is range(sheet.rows.count,1) To go up we use End(xlup) and then down one .offset(1,0)  That's One row, no columns. Put it together and we get range(sheets("sheet1").rows.count,1).end(xlup).offset(1,0)
So your line is

```
Sheets("Summary Build").Range("A6:F24").Copy Destination:=range(sheets("sheet1").rows.count,1).end(xlup).offset(1,0)
```

To put today's date into a cell you can use the date function eg:

```
Range("A2") = Date()
```

EDIT: Sorry it should read

```
Sheets(1).Range("A6:F24").Copy _
Destination:=Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Sheets("sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

Comment: appreciate the help.  When attempting that I get the error Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed - not sure what that means

Comment: see my edit - clearly I was having a "senior moment" yesterday